# Cannot animate width of an element using CSS Animation

Tags: html, css

I am using animations in CSS but it is not working. If I check in the inspect menu it is showing invalid syntax even though the syntax is normal. I have other two animations but they are working fine.
Only a particular animation in which I am trying to adjust the width isn't working.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-div {
  background: url(imgs/sky.png);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: 79% 792px;
  background-position-y: -332px;
  width: 900vw;
}

.sea-div {
  background: url(imgs/sea.jpg);
  height: 37vh;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 900vw;
  background-size: 10% 403px;
}

.bg-ani-class {
  animation: seaMove linear infinite 3s;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.sea-ani-class {
  animation: seaMove linear infinite 6s;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.obst-ani-class {
  animation: obstMove linear 5s;
}

.mountain-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  /* width: 18vh; */
  /* height: 20vh; */
  left: 108vw;
}

.mountain-div img {
  width: 148vh;
}

.hanuman-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28vh;
  left: 3vw;
}

.hanuman-div img {
  width: 20vw;
}

#gada {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  /* top: 56px; */
  transition: 0.1s ease all;
}

.gada-rot {
  left: 8vw !important;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  top: -22px !important;
}

.laser {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateZ(189deg);
  /* top: -14vh; */
  left: 282px;
  /* width: 45vw !important; */
  width: 0% !important;
  /* transition: 0.4s ease-out; */
  animation: laserAnimation infinite 3s;
}

.dragon-1-div {}

.dragon-2-div {}


/* Animations */


/* These 2 Animations are working */

@keyframes seaMove {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-500vw);
  }
}

@keyframes obstMove {
  0% {
    left: 108vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: -100vw;
  }
}


/* This animation isn't working */

@keyframes laserAnimation {
  from {
    width: 0 !important;
  }
  to {
    width: 45vw !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-div bg-ani-class"></div>
<div class="sea-div sea-ani-class"></div>
<div class="hanuman-div">
  <img src="imgs/hanuman.png" alt="">
  <img src="imgs/gada.png" alt="" id="gada">
  <img src="imgs/laserbeam.png" alt="" class="laser">
</div>
<div class="mountain-div">
  <img src="imgs/mountain.png" alt="">
</div>
<div class="dragon-1-div"></div>
<div class="dragon-2-div"></div>
```

Comment: Hello!
Please, uptade the question with a code snippet, so we can run it.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, if you could post a reproducible example that would be great. Also, I recommend you look into `transition` for these small animations going from just one state to another. Keyframes are for more complicated animations.

Comment: Don't use `!important` , particularly here, you are trying to override `!important` with `!important`, which is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to animate width and height. Always try to use composite animations e.g. opacity, transforms. To achieve width animation use scale transform.
Here is a laser show for you:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.laser {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #d7272b;
  animation: laserAnimation 2s ease-out infinite;
}

.greenLaser {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #0063d5;
  animation: laserAnimation 2s ease-out infinite;
}

.blueLaser {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00d53b;
  animation: laserAnimation 2s ease-out infinite;
}

@keyframes laserAnimation {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="laser">
</div>
<div class="greenLaser">
</div>
<div class="blueLaser">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes should I make in my code?

Comment: Set the width of the element to 100% or whatever value you want and animate from scaleX(0) to scaleX(1). See example in my code snippet